# C++ Can someone explain me this << and >> operation overloaded for showing a class content?

Tags: c++, operators, overloading

I hope this question don't get banned to me.

It's a knoob question, but i don't know how the things are working here.

I have the following **istream** and **ostream** overloaded **<<** and **>>** operators. I did it with a **friend** function.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Employee {
    std::string name;
    int age;
public:
    Employee(std::string p_name = "", int p_age = 0)
    {
        name = p_name;
        age = p_age;
    }
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& s, Employee& e);
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& s, Employee& e);
};

std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& s, Employee& e)
{
   std::cout << "\nEnter name: "; s >> e.name;
   std::cout << "\nEnter age: "; s >> e.age;
   return s;
}
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& s, Employee& e)
{
    s << "Name: " << e.name << std::endl;
    s << "Age:" << e.age << std::endl;
    return s;
}
int main()
{
    const int MAX = 1024;
    Employee emp1("Lucas", 40), emp2("Disch", 35);
    std::cout << "Employee 1 is: \n" << emp1 << '\n'
              << "Employee 2 is: \n" << emp2 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

If we have the >> and << operator overloaded and an operator overloaded is like a function() why when, in the main() function the line:

```
std::cout << "Employee 1 is: \n" << emp1 << '\n'
          << "Employee 2 is: \n" << emp2 << std::endl;
```

only recives the Employee class and automatically the ostream and the istream is passed/recived doing the << or >>?

Please i have search google i don't get answers.

As anyone can see im kinda lost with I/O in C++ and search and google doesn't make things clear. Even questions here in stackoverflow.

If admin wants to bann me it's ok, i deserve it.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on *only recives the Employee class and automatically the ostream and the istream is passed/recived doing the << or >>?*  It's not clear to me what you are asking.  Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).  In it, they will go over operator overloading for classes and how it works.

Comment: `operator<<` and `operator>>` are binary operators.  Doing `cout << emp` is the same as calling `operator<<(cout, emp)`; it's syntactic sugar.

Comment: Thanks very much. Now it's more clear to me. Any book/link suggestion that teaches the IO in C++? I'm not talking about the Stratroup definition of the languaje. Thxs.

Comment: First, because of operator associativity, `std::cout << "Employee 1 is: \n" << emp1` is the same as `(std::cout << "Employee 1 is: \n") << emp1`. Now since `operator<<` and `operator>>` by convention return the left hand side, that means that it's basically like doing `std::cout << "Employee 1 is: \n"; std::cout << emp1`.

Comment: As mention above this is "syntactic sugar". Main problem is that may newbies think this is important thing to learn it is cool and so on. It is not. Focus your effort on something else. When you improve your skills in other areas then understudying this feature will take you 5 minutes. Now it will take you whole day or more.

Comment: Marek R you are right. I should try those steps